# Return everything before the last "/"

Tags: regex, bash

I would like a regular expression that will do the following:

1. Given a directory, return the previous directory. So, basically remove the last "/" and everything after it. You can assume that the string will not end in "/something/" but instead will be "/something".
2. Examples:

   1. - Given: "**/home/development**"
      - Return: "**/home**"
   2. - Given: "**/home/simulations/database**"
      - Return: "**/home/simulations**"
   3. - Given: "**/home/simulations/workingConfig/system/customer**"
      - Return: "**/home/simulations/workingConfig/system**"
   4. etc.

I've been playing around with a regular expression like `/[^/]*$` and the command like:

`expr match "/home/simulations/database" '\(/[^/]*$\)'`

with no luck. Any help?

Comment: Hmm. To what extent is it being a regex an innate part of the question? (Shell pattern matches are regular expressions in the formal sense, but they don't comply with POSIX re syntax, being specified in a different part of the standard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an external command such as `sed` is needlessly inefficient; bash can do this built-in with [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
s=${s%/*}
```

This does a non-greedy [pattern match](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) for `/*` at the end of your string and removes everything it finds. Thus:

```
$ s=/home/simulations/database
$ echo "${s%/*}"
/home/simulations
```

See also [BashFAQ #100 ("How can I do string manipulations in bash?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

---

That said, if you *really* want to use a regular expression, bash can do that too with only built-in functionality:

```
$ s=/home/simulations/database
$ [[ $s =~ ^(.*)/[^/]*$ ]] && s=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo "$s"
/home/simulations
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `dirname`

```
$ dirname /home/development /home/simulations/database /home/simulations/workingConfig/system/customer
/home
/home/simulations
/home/simulations/workingConfig/system
```

Comment: +1: Better tool for the job when working with filenames (for instance, knows that the dirname of `barename` is `.`), even if using it is a bit more expensive (requiring a fork to capture output).

Comment: Didn't think of that! Thanks glenn!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `sed` for this, since it is pretty straight forward:

```
sed 's@/[^/]*$@@' <<< "string"
```

This removes everything from the last `/`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
/home/simulations/workingConfig/system/customer
/home/simulations/database
/home/development

$ sed 's@/[^/]*$@@' a
/home/simulations/workingConfig/system
/home/simulations
/home
```

Comment: Yess!! This worked! Thank you! I'll press the accept button in 10 min when it lets me. lol.